# Is there a way to automate installing modules for users within a Python script?

Tags: python, automation, module, pip, python-module

I wanted to use the *colorama* and *distro* package, but they have to be manually installed with *pip*. Is there a way to somehow automate the installation, so a user can just run a script and everything will be installed for him?

Comment: The common approaches would be to either write a `requirements.txt` for `pip` or to define a `setup.py` containing dependencies that could be used with `pip` or to build packages for installation (rpm, deb etc).

Comment: Write all of the packages in your environment to a requirements.txt file using `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.  Then `pip install -r requirements.txt` will automate the installation of all the packages.  What you are wanting to do may be a good use case for a Docker container.  You could automate the installation in a Docker container using a Dockerfile.

Comment: you can run `import` in `try/except` to catch missing modules and use `pip.main(["install", ...])` inside `except` to install missing module. But more popular is to use `requirements.txt` for this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way was to add a `requirements.txt` file for `pip` to install everything.